# -nomultimonitor option does not work correctly in XMing with Java applications

Tags: multiple-monitors, java, xming

This is my monitor config:

[image]

I am running remote applications and display it's windows on my client computer with the help of `Xming`

If I use `nomultimonitor` option along with `multiwindow`, it glitches.

For example, Eclipse starting logo shows in incorrect place:

[image]

I.e. it draws above the top of the second screen (left).

If I unhide Xming root window, java windows appears twice:

[image]

I.e. Xming window correctly occupies the center of screen #1, and "think" that windows are in it's center, but does not draw window frames, while actually windows are located on second screen and captures mouse events from there.

Applications like `xcalc` works correctly.